# Toggle div tag on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many buttons with id `b1`, `b2` ... and each has a `div` tag after it with id `q1`, `q2`...
I want to toggle the `div` tag when the corresponding button is clicked. **Example:** When `b1` is clicked `q1` should toggle. 
It is given here. http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/topper/en-toppers.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".info").hide();
  $("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#q1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></button>
    
<div id="q1" class="info"></div>
```

But as i might have 100 of buttons, how can i do the same thing without adding click on each button?

Comment: `$('.btn').on('click', function(){ $(this).next().toggle(); });`

Comment: Does each div come directly after the corresponding button? No elements between the two?

Comment: yes, there is nothing between the two . its same as  i have mentioned above

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError your code is working. my doubt is do i need to add id to button anymore as well as id / class to div tag.

Comment: No, that would be unnecessary, I would add a unique class though that you can use as a selector specifically for this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *attribute startswith selector* `^`, get the `id` of button and get the index value from it first.

```
$("[id^='b']").click(function(){
    var index = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $("#q" + index ).toggle();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".info").hide();
  $("[id^='b']").click(function() {
    var index = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $("#q" + index).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button1</button>
<div id="q1" class="info">Info1</div>

<button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button2</button>
<div id="q2" class="info">Info2</div>

<button id="b3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button3</button>
<div id="q3" class="info">Info3</div>

<button id="b4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button4</button>
<div id="q4" class="info">Info4</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(".info").hide();
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).next('div.info').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button 1</button>
    
<div class="info">Div 1</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button 2</button>
    
<div class="info">Div 2</div>
```

No need to targeting using id, you can do it using `jQuery .next()`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why did you duplicate IDs? Also, how about an explanation as to what you did instead of just "here you go"?

Comment: @j08691 It was a mistake of duplicating the `id`s, I've  updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your selector from `$("#b1")` to something like `$(".btn")`, and then use the `id` to determine which `q` you want to open, like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  if(this.id){
    $("#q"+this.id.substring(1)).toggle();
  }
});
```

This way, it doesn't matter how you arrange your HTML, as long as the ids match

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".info").hide();
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    if(this.id){
      $("#q"+this.id.substring(1)).toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">b1</button>
<button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">b2</button>
    
<div id="q1" class="info">q1</div>
<div id="q2" class="info">q2</div>
```

Here you have it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/py8q340p/

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra variable state to check your state and for first time only your first div is toggled later on both the divs are toggled.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var state = 0;
  $(".info").hide();
  $("#b1").click(function(){
if(state ==0 ) {
   $('#q1').toggle();
state = 1;

 
}
   else  { 
       $("#q1").toggle();
$('#q2').toggle();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Toggle Divs</button>
    
<div id="q1" class="info">Hello div 1</div>
<div id="q2" class="info">Hello div 2</div>
```